# Find all paragraphs of text that are related to a topic

Tags: regex, nlp

Given a set of words `["college", "sports", "coding"]`, and a set of paragraphs of text (i.e. facebook posts), how can I see for each word the paragraphs that are related to that topic?

So for college, how can I find all the paragraphs of text that may be about the topic college?

I'm new to natural language processing, and not very advanced at regex. Clues about how to get started, what the right terms to google, etc are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic ideea would be to iterate over your posts and see if any post matches any of the topic.

Let's say we have the following posts:

> Post 1:
> Dadadad adada college fgdssfgoksh jkhsfdkjshdkj sports hfjkshgkjshgjhsdgjkhskjgfs.
>
> Post 2:
> Sports dadadad adada fgdssfgoksh jkhsfdkjshdkj hfjkshgkjshgjhsdgjkhskjgfs.
>
> Post 3:
> Coding adskjdsflkshdflksjlg lsdjk hsjdkh kdsafkj asfjkhsa coding fhksajhdf kjhskfhsfd ssdggsd.

and the following topics:

> ["college", "sports", "coding"]

The regex could be: `(topicName)+`

E.g.: `(college)+` or `(sports)+` or `(coding)+`

Small pseudocode:

```
for every topicName
    for every post
        var customRegex = new RegExp('(' + topicName + ')+');

        if customRegex.test(post) then
            //post matches topicName
        else
            //post doesn't match topicName
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Hope it could give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Exact string matching won't take you far, especially with small fragments of text. I suggest you to use [semantic similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity) for this. A simple web search will give several implementations.